# Can I acces variables and/or methods of the class a JFrame was created in from the panel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

shortened code:

```
public class Test{
  private JFrame frame;
  private TestPanel panel;
  
  Object obj;
 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test test = new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    try {
      // Setup GUI
      frame = new JFrame("Test");
      panel = new TestPanel();
      frame.add(panel);
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to directly access obj from panel?
If yes: How?

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: I don't exactly get what you mean by "from the panel". Can you specify that a bit more?

Comment: I am writing a method in Testpanel which needs to call a method from obj. (in my case: obj is a JChannel and I create a Message in a method in Testpanel, but can't find a way to call the send method of the JChannel)

Comment: I see. I don't think what you mean is possible, because neither the `frame` nor the `panel` have a reference to `obj`. What is stopping you from passing the reference to `obj` to the `panel` via constructor or setter for example?

Comment: The task is to modify the code so the drawings synchronize. It's never specified what exactly we are allowed to edit, so I try to only add things where we are specifically told to do so and not to touch any of the existing stuff. ^^ But I think I will pass "this" in the constructor of the panel so I have access to everything. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; Not without passing the reference to object to the panel.